# Only have single domain certificates but wan't to load data from a sub domain without warnings

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate

I have a certificate that validates a single domain name (https://www.example.com) and I've setup nginx to use that certificate.
On the page I wan't to link to images from a subdomain I own (images.example.com). I also have a valid certificate for images.example.com.

How to I prevent the browser from warning me that content on www.example.com is not secure (because it has loaded content from /images.example.com). Can I add my images.example.com certificate to the nginx config in any way or is my only option to buy a certificate for *.example.com? Can I combine my two certificates into one that recognizes both domains as safe?

Comment: Please include your Nginx configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You either need two IPs, one for each site; or you need to get one certificate that has both names (or a wildcard) on it. You can't combine two certificates yourself.